# How to change Camera Preview Buffer Resolution?

Tags: camera, windows-phone-7.1

Is there any way to change the Camera Preview Buffer Resolution? I can change the normal camera `Resolution` but I'm not able to figure out a way for changing the `PreviewResolution`

I can get the `PreviewResolution` width and height by using :

```
PhotoCamera photoCamera = new PhotoCamera();
int width = photoCamera.PreviewResolution.Width;
int height = photoCamera.PreviewResolution.Height;
```

But I need to set `PreviewResolution` and I'm using Windows Phone 7.1 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can change the PreviewResolution. I have only ever seen it as 640x 480.

If you are using it as a source for the VideoBrush, it should scale (or shrink) to fill the size of the grid you are using it as a background for. In your XAML definition you can also play with the Stretch (possible values of "Uniform", "Fill", "UniformToFill" and "None").

Comment: Hi thank you, I'm displaying it on VideoBrush as well as I'm saving continuous images from PreviewBuffer to IsolatedStorage. So I need higher quality images rather then using Stretch property. Also I'm getting `640x480` on `Nokia Lumia 800`

Comment: Your right it is 640 x 480 (updated answer above). I have not been able to do what you were after and have just been working with the PreviewBuffer.